# Opinion what's a better solution to avoid overlapping content (multi upload)

Tags: jquery, css, forms, file-upload

I build a form on a Wordpress site using the Ninja Forms plugin. I needed to style the file upload button. The best solution
(cross-browser compatible) that I found was this tutorial:

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/

I managed to style the button as intended, however I’m facing two issues
now:

a) The file list is now overlapping the following content once more than one file is selected.

b) I’m not able to give ‘MultiFile-wrap’ overflow:hidden without
hiding the file list.

I'm thinking of using one of the two following solutions:

Somehow try to move ‘MultiFile-list’ out of its parent
(MultiFile-wrap) in the DOM. (Perhaps using jQuery)

or

Use jQuery to count how many items are currently in the list and add a margin to the contant below accordingly.

I'm not sure which would be the better approach. I tend to use the second approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went for option number one, as it seemed to be the cleaner approach, and it allowed me to give ‘MultiFile-wrap’ overflow:hidden.

It took a bit for me to understand that ‘MultiFile-list’ is created dynamically so I had to bind the function to a click event.

Here's what did the trick:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload-wrap .MultiFile-wrap', function () {
  $('.upload-wrap .MultiFile-wrap .MultiFile-list').insertBefore('.nf-desc');
});
```